# Convert TimeStamp To Date On Property Itself in DocumentDb

Tags: timestamp, azure-cosmosdb

I  know how to convert TimeStamp to Date inside the methods, but i want to implement something on my property to convert the TimeStamp of the last updated document in DocumentDb. Something like below--

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="_ts")]
    /*    What to insert here --   [JsonConverter(typeof(???))]     */                 
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Please don't give methods to implement in the code. I need something to convert in property itself.

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDb stores the Timestamp value in the Unix Timestamp format (the number of seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00 UTC), so you need to write your own converter to decorate your properties with. Here is an example:

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Converters
{
    public class UnixDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
            object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            long seconds;
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                var dt = (DateTime)value;
                seconds = !dt.Equals(DateTime.MinValue) ?
                    new DateTimeOffset(dt).ToUnixTimeSeconds() : long.MinValue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Expected date object value.");
            }

            writer.WriteValue(seconds);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return null;

            if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Integer)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    $"Unexpected token parsing date. Expected Integer, got {reader.TokenType}.");
            }

            var seconds = (long)reader.Value;
            return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(seconds).DateTime;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
        }
    }
}
```

Bear in mind that this code will only work on .NET 4.6  - in order to target earlier frameworks, you should make the conversion yourself.